# Place The Cursor On UITextView Where User Touches

Tags: iphone, ios, textview, ios6, uitextview

Hey all i want to set the position of cursor of UITextView in iphone. My scnerio is i write a text on UITextView "Hello World" and i touch between "Hello" and "World" and cursor moves there. And after that when i insert some input from keyboard the cursor automatically moves at the end of the text. So is there any way that cursor remains on the place where user touches. Thanks. And one more thing i am using iOS6 so kindly tell those solutions which are compatible with iOS6 as well.
I am using different languages so when keyboard changes the alignment of UITextView changes as well using following line of code.

```
     txtView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

The cursor normally moves by zooming on tap and hold and then moving to the desired position.

Comment: my problem after the cursor is set to the desired  position and is if i moved the cursor between hello and world and after that insert an input the cursor automatically moves at the end of the hello world and write there.
Actual Scnerio "Hello|World" a-> "Hello Worlda"
Desired Scnerio "Hello|World" a-> "HelloaWorld".